# How not to use dependency in domain context when using vendor event dispatcher

Tags: php, events, domain-driven-design

I'm looking into using DDD for a sample application, for now I'm stuck on  Domain Events. Since there are pretty good EventDispatchers out there I don't want to reinvent the wheel. But these implementations all require that my events are implementing their EventInterface. I want to keep the implementation of my Domain Events seperate from any kind of implementation. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at guava eventbus ? No EventInterface there I think https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained

Comment: Maybe consider also sending your domain event from the application layer, in that case IMO it is an issue to have a dependency on a fwk. I am saying this because sometimes inside a bounded context you do not need domain events. So maybe your events will be used only outside your context

Comment: @RonanQuillevere I'm using PHP but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities I can think of

1) Introduce the idea of an adapter in front of the EventDispatcher; the adapter accepts events in the format produced by the domain, and "serializes" that same data into the form required by the specific dispatcher implementation you are using.

2) Create the domain events using a builder api; the domain defines the builder contract, but the implementation under the covers is specific to the event dispatcher you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I created the adapter so I can change my whole infrastructure layer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my impl:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the contract for publishing domain events.
/// </summary>
public interface IDomainEventPublisher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the domain events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainEvents">events to be published</param>
    Task Publish(IEnumerable domainEvents);

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes the list of subscribers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subscribers">event subscriptions</param>
    void Subscribe(params IDomainEventSubscription[] subscribers);

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes to the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">event to subscribe too</typeparam>
    /// <returns>event subscription</returns>
    DomainEventSubscription<T> SubscribeTo<T>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Publishes events to registered subscribers.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultDomainEventPublisher : IDomainEventPublisher
{
    readonly List<IDomainEventSubscription> subscriptions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the object.
    /// </summary>
    public DefaultDomainEventPublisher()
    {
        subscriptions = new List<IDomainEventSubscription>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes to the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">event to subscribe too</typeparam>
    /// <returns>event subscription</returns>
    public DomainEventSubscription<T> SubscribeTo<T>()
    {
        var subscription = new DomainEventSubscription<T>();

        subscriptions.Add(subscription);

        return subscription;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes the list of subscribers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subscribers">event subscriptions</param>
    public void Subscribe(params IDomainEventSubscription[] subscribers)
    {
        subscriptions.AddRange(subscribers);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the domain events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainEvents">events to be published</param>
    public virtual async Task Publish(IEnumerable domainEvents)
    {
        foreach (var @event in domainEvents)
        {
            var subscribers = subscriptions.Where(s => s.CanHandleType(@event.GetType()));

            foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
            {
                await subscriber.Handle(@event);
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the subscription services for an event.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class DomainEventSubscription<T> : IDomainEventSubscription
{
    readonly List<object> subscriptionMethods;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance.
    /// </summary>
    public DomainEventSubscription()
    {
        this.subscriptionMethods = new List<object>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the subscription method to the subscription.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subscriptionMethod">subscription method</param>
    public void AddSubscriptionMethod(ISubscriptionMethod subscriptionMethod)
    {
        subscriptionMethods.Add(subscriptionMethod);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether or not the subscription can handle the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns>whether it can handle the type</returns>
    public bool CanHandleType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">event to publish</param>
    public async Task Handle(object @event)
    {
        foreach (var subscriptionMethod in subscriptionMethods)
        {
            await (subscriptionMethod as dynamic).Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contains the contract for event subscribers.
/// </summary>
public interface IDomainEventSubscription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">event to publish</param>
    Task Handle(object @event);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether or not the subscription can handle the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns>whether it can handle the type</returns>
    bool CanHandleType(Type type);
}

/// <summary>
/// Contacts the contract for subscription methods.
/// </summary>
public interface ISubscriptionMethod
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">event to publish</param>
    Task Handle(object @event);
}

/// <summary>
/// Base class for subscription method implementations.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public abstract class SubscriptionMethod : ISubscriptionMethod
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">event to publish</param>
    public abstract Task Handle(object @event);
}

/// <summary>
/// Publishes events using delegates.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class DelegateSubscriptionMethod<T> : ISubscriptionMethod
{
    readonly Func<T, Task> delegateAction;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">delegate used for publishing</param>
    public DelegateSubscriptionMethod(Func<T, Task> action)
    {
        delegateAction = action;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the event using a delegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">event to publish</param>
    public async Task Handle(object @event)
    {
        await delegateAction(@event as dynamic);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides an extension method for publishing an event using a delegate.
/// </summary>
public static class DomainEventSubscriptionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an event subscription for publishing using the specified delegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">event the subscription is subscribed too</typeparam>
    /// <param name="subscription">event subscription</param>
    /// <param name="action">delegate used for publishing</param>
    /// <returns>event subscription</returns>
    public static DomainEventSubscription<T> UsingDelegate<T>(this DomainEventSubscription<T> subscription, Func<T, Task> action)
    {
        var subscriptionMethod = new DelegateSubscriptionMethod<T>(action);

        subscription.AddSubscriptionMethod(subscriptionMethod);

        return subscription;
    }
}
```

Here is some basic usage:

```
publisher.SubscribeTo<DocumentOwnerChanged>()
    .UsingDelegate(
        async a => await messageGateway.DocumentOwnerChanged(1, 1, 1));
```

I also have an implementation to auto-subscribe using my DI container. Let me know if you would like to see this as well.

Comment: This is a solution, but unfortunately I'm using PHP and was about to use a vendor package.